# Get React Intellisense on this react-boilerplate in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using this [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) and I want to have the inteliSense working on my Visual Studio Code.

I have installed the react typings `typings install react` and it installs on the `./typings/` folder of the root directory. While the `jsconfig.json` is set to ES6.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

when i try to create a component in the `./app/components/` directory, no intellisense when i type `class H4 extends React.`